# Get data from Json Response using C#

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio-2012

I have the following code in a Unit Test:

```
        SomeModel test = new SomeModel();
        test.TestField = "Some Content Here"; //Where TestField is a String attribute of the SomeModel class

        var expected = Json(test, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

When I run

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Expected " + expected.Data.ToString());
```

I get this in the output: `Expected Fake.Path.SomeModel`

When I run the test through the debugger I am able to see the data:
[image: Debugger Result]

**How can I access the data through my unit test?** I want to be able to verify that the data in it is correct through automated tests.

I am using Visual Studio 2012 Professional

Thanks!

Comment: The default `ToString` is just to show the type name, which is what you are seeing. If you want the message, it's going to be `expected.Data.TestField`

Comment: I get an error when I do that: 'Object' does not contain reference for 'TestField'

Comment: Then cast it. `((SomeModel)expected.Data).TestField)`

Comment: @MattBurland Beautiful!!!! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default implementation (in `Object`) of `ToString` is to display the type name. That's what you are seeing when you do this:

```
expected.Data.ToString()
```

If you want to get at the actual `TestField`, and `Data` is defined as object, then you need:

```
((SomeModel)expected.Data).TestField
```

Answer (score 0):

I would download Newtonsoft's JSON library from NuGet if you haven't already. This is the code I used on one of my applications which used that libraries `JObject` class:

```
var parsed = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
JToken token;
if (parsed.TryGetValue("Key", out token))
{
    var value = token.ToString();
    ... //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: JObject.Parse only takes string arguments. Is there a way to parse the JsonResult?

Comment: `myJsonResult.ToString()` or maybe `myJsonResult.Data.ToString()` whichever returns the JSON formatted string containing the data.

Comment: See Matt's response in the original question. His solution worked perfectly for me!